# What is the cause of the Security Constraints Not Satisfied Error when using sam deploy ---guided?

Tags: aws-sam-cli

I am attempting to follow the [Hello World example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html) for deploying an AWS Serverless Application, but I get a Security Constraints Not Satisfied Error when using `sam deploy --guided`. I'm pressing Enter at each prompt to accept the defaults per the tutorial.

The curious bit--to me--is if I use the AWS Toolkit extension for VS Code to deploy the app it works fine, so I don't think it has anything to do with my IAM permission config, but I'm new to this so I'm not ruling it out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Recently the guided deploy was updated to include a prompt confirming if you were ok with not having any authorization defined. At the same time, a check was added that would fail the guided deploy if you answer 'No'. (See the [relevant part of the commit here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/commit/849f28ca818945fde6e783598dfd37319a3120d5#diff-be0e0048c59b165ab3d16b3f87d6544eR125-R130).)

This means that, as of this commit, you can't go through the [AWS Hello World tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html#serverless-getting-started-hello-world-deploy) by responding with `Enter` to accept the default options.

To successfully deploy from the command line you'll need to confirm 'Yes' that you're ok with not having any authorization defined, and then it should work as expected.

Comment: Bonus tip that caught me out: if you're using profiles in your `~/.aws/credentials` file and selecting them via the AWS Toolkit extension for VS Code, you'll need to add the `--profile` flag when on the command line. See `sam deploy --help` for details.

Answer (score 8):

During your `sam deploy --guided`, at the following question you need to answer **YES**.

[image]

OR

You can do `sam deploy` which skip that

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when `aws configure` configured to use different region, changing region to the correct user region resolved me the issue